# ¿Cómo obtener una lista de las bases de datos existentes en Postgresql usando Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, base-de-datos, postgresql

Deseo mostrar al usuario una lista con las bases de datos existentes en postgresql para que escoja a cual conectarce. Solo he encontrado respuestas como en https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1285/how-do-i-list-all-databases-and-tables-using-psql/1304#1304 usando comandos desde el terminal como:

```
\list or \l: list all databases
```

Pero como hacerlo directamente desde Python.

Answer (score 2):

*Postgres* tiene un catálogo con metadatos de las bases de datos que maneja  [pg_database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-database.html). Tan sólo tienes que hacer una consulta usando `pg_database` como tabla:

```
dbs = cursor.fetchall("SELECT datname FROM pg_database")
```

Comment: Disculpa soy nuevo en python me podrías indicar que tipo de variable es cursor para que tenga el método fetchall

Comment: En python, el acceso a base de datos se hace a través de un interface común llamado [DB-API](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingDbApiWithPostgres). Deberías conocerlo antes de usar cualquier bases de datos. Para postgres, el interface más popular es [psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/).

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que podrías llamar a la funcion list de un shell y leer la salida que esta entrega para luego procesarla y mostrarla al usuario como quieres.

Para esto debes de usar subprocess, este sería un ejemplo:

```
subprocess.check_output(["\list"])
```